# How do I get the URI from a CloseableHttpResponse

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

When I get a `CloseableHttpResponse` object for the response to a web request, and the request was successful, how do I get the ***URI*** of the response?

Comment: Why? You forgot it already? Anyway you can't. It isn't in there.

Comment: The response uri can be different from the request uri if there was a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

One can get this information from `HttpContext` associated with the message exchange

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .build();
HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet("http://google.com/"), clientContext)) {
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    EntityUtils.consume(entity);

    final HttpRequest request = clientContext.getRequest();
    System.out.println(request.getRequestLine().getUri());
    System.out.println(request.getFirstHeader("Host"));
    final List<URI> redirectLocations = clientContext.getRedirectLocations();
    System.out.println(redirectLocations);
}
```

Comment: I think that's the request uri, not the response uri. And they are different if there's a redirect at the request uri.

Comment: @DavidThielen There is no such thing as a response URI in HTTP.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirectlocation?view=netframework-4.8